# Many to many validation in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model which has a many-to-many field in it. I am interested to know how and where should I implement a check on those elements.

Example:

```
class Tire(models.Model):
    type = ('front-left','front-right','rear-left','rear-right')

class Car(models.Model):
    tires = models.ManyToManyField('Tire')
```

When creating a Car object I want to disallow the Car to have tires of the same type.

Thank you

EDIT 1:

Yeah ... so the problem is that one Tire can belong to multiple Cars which does not make much sense ... but this is how it is.

Comment: I think it makes more sense to make the `Car` model as `ForeignKey` in model `Tire`, and make `type` as a choice field instead. Then you make `unique_together` on `type` and `car` in `Tire` model. Does that make sense?

Comment: I agree with @ShangWang, your Tire object seemingly represents a unique object, meaning one tire should not be 'installed on more than one car'.

Comment: Aaa ... sorry. You are completely right. I presented the situation wrongly. I will edit.

Comment: I think this may be what you want ...
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2552/ (checking for unique_together on a many-to-many field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's acceptable for you to assign to which wheel tire will be used each time you're assigning it to car, maybe better way will be to have `through` model:

```
class Tire(models.Model):

    # your tire fields

class Car(models.Model):

    # car fields
    tires = models.ManyToMany(Tire, through="CarTire")

class CarTire(models.Model):

    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name="car_tire")
    tire = models.ForeignKey(Tire)

    tire_type = models.CharField(choices=types)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [
            ('car', 'tire_type'),
        ]
```

That way it will be guaranteed on database level that each car will have only one tire of each type.